# Plotting a `geom_rug` on both sides of the plot (left and right) based on `x` value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

### Problem Statement

Suppose that I have the following function of two variables

```
f <- function(x, y){
    return(x*y + (x^3)*sin(y))
}
```

I want to fix two `x` points, for instance at `x=2` and `x=3` and then, I want to get, say, `100` standard random normal samples, which I'm going to feed in as `y` values.

### What the data looks like

This is what the data looks like

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(
    x = c(rep(2, 50), rep(3, 50)), 
    y=c(f(2, head(y, 50)), f(3, tail(y, 50)))
)
head(df)
```

```
  x         y
1 2 -5.943113
2 2  1.828189
3 2 -7.605003
4 2 11.188164
5 2  3.247634
6 2 -7.492659
```

### Standard Scatter Plot of the data

```
df$x <- as.factor(df$x)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image: scatterplot]

## What I am trying to do

Basically I want to have two `geom_rug()` one on the left, corresponding to the scatter points for `x=2` and one on right, corresponding to the scatter plot for `x=3`. I can produce a `geom_rug()` for all scatter points, as shown below, but I don't know how to have two different

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=x)) + 
    geom_rug()
```

[image: rug]

Ideally, I'd like the rug plot on the left to have the same color as the scatter points on `x=2`, and the rug plot on the right to have the same color as the scatter points on `x=3`.

Comment: Actually, i think I might have solved it. I used
`ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=x)) + geom_point(aes(color=x)) + geom_rug(data=subset(df, x==2), sides="l", aes(y=y)) + geom_rug(data=subset(df, x==3), sides="r")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, I did solve the problem by using

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=x)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=x)) + 
  geom_rug(data=subset(df, x==2), sides="l", aes(y=y)) + 
  geom_rug(data=subset(df, x==3), sides="r")
```